# What will happen if takeLeadership() never return when using Curator's Leader Election

Tags: apache-zookeeper, distributed-system, apache-curator

```
LeaderSelectorListener listener = new LeaderSelectorListenerAdapter()
    {
        public void takeLeadership(CuratorFramework client) throws Exception
        {
            while (true) {
               try {
                 // ... business logic
               } catch (Exception e) {  // catch any exeption here
                 // do nothing
               }
             }
        }
    }
LeaderSelector selector = new LeaderSelector(client, path, listener);
selector.autoRequeue();
selector.start();
```

As the code shows, I catched any exception in the business code, so even zookeeper disconnects, the business code will still be executing, right ?

Comment: Is this Java? And what is the purpose of this code (what does it do)?

Comment: yes, this is code based on curator framework, which is just an example. Suppose I have 3 machines, but I want only 1 of these machines will run the business logic in takeLeadership().

Answer (score 0):

If zookeeper disconnects, the business code will not be executing.

Class `LeaderSelectorListenerAdapter` has a method `stateChanged()`.

This method will throw a `CancelLeadershipException`, which makes client exit and requeue for leadership, when zk was in `SUSPENDED` or `LOST`.

So, don't worry.